# Access .sqlite file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite, netbeans, jruby

I have a .sqlite file, and I wanted to know how I can go about querying the database using Built in Ruby within the NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Have you tried Googling for the answer?

Comment: Yes and I don't seem to understand the answers, does it involve using Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Not necessarily, if you don't need a web framework you can just use Sqlite gem (see Victor's answer). Or you can take middle road and use just ORM.

Comment: To note, I'm using Built in JRuby and it does seem to have an sqlite package within it. I can't seem to reference sqlite within my project though

Comment: I'm guessing that you are coming from Java or .NET background. :) I'd advise you to skip using Netbeans for start and start editing all your project files by hand. There is no such thing as "adding a reference" in Ruby. Just installing and requiring a gem (which is the point of Victor's answer below).

Comment: Oh, you probably realize that you should have mentioned that you are using JRuby in the start.

Comment: Yeh I did realise that after answers were given..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sqlite3` gem for this,

```
gem install sqlite3
```

And then from ruby code:

```
require 'sqlite'

db = SQLite::Database.new "path/to/file.sqlite"
db.execute "WRITE YOUR QUERY HERE"
```

Also look at [sqlite3 documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/1.3.6/frames).